# Adding frame to a VBA UserForm Causes Runtime error 75

Tags: vba

I'm having trouble adding a Frame to a UserForm. On a blank UserForm if I add a frame to the UserForm I can veiw it just fine in VBE but if I open it I get an runtime error 75 Path not found. If I remove the Frame it opens fine. Anyone run into an issue like this before or have any input?

Comment: Have you tried other user controls from toolbox. Are you facing same issue with other controls also or just frame.

Comment: @Alok Seems like just the Frame.

Comment: is it possible to share the screen shot of the error you are getting?

Comment: @Alok Hi, I have been busy converting the UserForm to the Access Form all day. Gives me and excuse to leave VBA UserForms Behind :). I will try to load a screen shot when I get off.